# Не работает вычисление результата в калькуляторе на Vue

Tags: vue.js

Пишу калькулятор на Vue, все хорошо, но когда нажимаю на =, результат не подсчитывается, происходит ровным счётом ничего, как это исправить?

Вот код в App.vue

```
    <template>
  <div class="flex">
    <input v-model="inputValue" type="text" class="input" placeholder="0">
    <ul class="list">
      <li v-for="num in numbers" :key="num" @click="inputValue += String(num)" class="list-item" >
        {{ num }}
      </li>
      <li v-for="op in operations" :key="op" @click="inputValue += String(op)" class="list-item op">
        {{ op }}
      </li>
      <li class="list-item op C" @click="inputValue = ''">
        C
      </li>
      <li class="list-item op res" @click="result">
        =
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

let inputValue = ref('')
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
const operations = ['+', '-', '*', '/']
const result = () => {
  inputValue = eval(inputValue)
}
</script>

<style>
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.flex {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 15px grey;
}

.input {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: right;
  color: #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
}

.input::placeholder {
  color: #000;
}

.list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.list-item {
  width: 33.3333333333%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: rgb(24, 0, 0);
  cursor: pointer;
  border-right: 1px solid #FFDFC4;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFDFC4;
}

.list-item:last-child {
  width: 100%;
}

.op {
  background-color: orangered;
}

.op:last-child {
  background-color: rgb(155, 43, 2);
}

.C {
  background-color: red;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Вы похоже не внимательно прочли документацию про https://v3.ru.vuejs.org/ru/api/refs-api.html
далее вижу `eval` и покидаю вас с чувством отвращения :)

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, что пришло на замену eval во vue 3? Прочёл эту страницу, но нужного для себя не нашел

Comment: Вью не имеет отношения к https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval 

**происходит ровным счётом ничего** - ответ в первом примере из документации что предоставил выше... там еще после примера пишут **Если свойству ...**

Comment: Всё равно не понял, правда

Comment: Я пробовал и eval(inputValue.toString), и eval(inputValue.value), все равно ошибки, но самое интересное когда в v-bind:click передаю просто eval('5+5'), пишет ctx.eval is not a function

Comment: Вижу, что ref возвращает объект с единственным свойством value, но при передаче inputValue.value в eval мне пишет, что в eval было передано undefined

Comment: Методом проб и ошибок обнаружил, работает console.log(ref(eval(inputValue.value)).value, в консоль действительно выводит результат, но когда я эту же конструкцию присваиваю значению inputValue, мне возвращается undefined, подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value'), вот что я получаю :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script setup>
    import { ref } from 'vue'
    const inputValue = ref('') // это вью обект, не простая переменнаая
    const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
    const operations = ['+', '-', '*', '/']
    const result = () => {
        // тут достаточно сделать вот так
        inputValue.value = eval(inputValue.value)
    }
</script>

<template>
    <div class="flex">
      <input v-model="inputValue" type="text" class="input" placeholder="0">
      <ul class="list">
        <li v-for="num in numbers" :key="num" @click="inputValue += String(num)" class="list-item" >
          {{ num }}
        </li>
        <li v-for="op in operations" :key="op" @click="inputValue += String(op)" class="list-item op">
          {{ op }}
        </li>
        <li class="list-item op C" @click="inputValue = ''">
          C
        </li>
        <li class="list-item op res" @click="result">
          =
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</template>
```